# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sports Stack Exchange](http://sports.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: No longer relevant as the site is out of beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How can you find your correct size of cricket bat?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/how-can-you-find-your-correct-size-of-cricket-bat)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What are some techniques for masking a ping pong serve?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/what-are-some-techniques-for-masking-a-ping-pong-serve)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [0:0 score in basketball](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/00-score-in-basketball)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How to Perform a Hardflip on a skateboard?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/how-to-perform-a-hardflip-on-a-skateboard)

  **Net Score: -9** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 9)
- [What happen when two players touch the finish rope at same time in running?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/what-happen-when-two-players-touch-the-finish-rope-at-same-time-in-running)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What do refs do during halftime?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/what-do-refs-do-during-halftime)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Do batting scores in abandoned matches still count for your career stats?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2837/do-batting-scores-in-abandoned-matches-still-count-for-your-career-stats)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to determine the correct grip size for a tennis racquet?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2861/how-to-determine-the-correct-grip-size-for-a-tennis-racquet)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Different uniform/jersey for same team in American-Football](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/different-uniform-jersey-for-same-team-in-american-football)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)
- [Unique baseball scoring situation: Who gets the Win?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/unique-baseball-scoring-situation-who-gets-the-win)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)